# Rails 2.3 STI return all child classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I am using standard STI and want to create an input select on a form whose options are all child type of the parent class. So I'd like Parent.select_options to return ['Child1','Child2','Child3']

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  # kinda what I'd like except the descendants method is undefined in rails 2.3
  def self.select_options
    descendants.map{ |c| c.to_s }.sort
  end
end

class Child1 < Parent
end

class Child2 < Parent
end

class Child3 < Parent
end
```

view.html.haml

```
= f.input :parent_id, :as => :select, :collection => Parent.select_options, :prompt => true
```

UPDATE

Thanks to @nash and @jdeseno just need to add the following initializer using @jdeseno method:

```
%w[parent child1 child2 child3].each do |c|
  require_dependency File.join("app","models","#{c}.rb")
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a descendants method by hooking into `Class.inherited`:

```
class Parent
  @@descendants = []

  def self.inherited(klass)
    @@descendants << klass
  end

  def descendants
    @@descendants
  end
end

class A < Parent; end
class B < Parent; end
class C < Parent; end
```

Eg:

```
irb> Parent.new.descendants
[A, B, C]
```

Comment: Worked great with a minor tweak. I needed to set up an initializer that preloaded the models since in development 'config.cache_classes == false'

Answer (score 2):

Actually, custom-implementing the tracking of subclasses isn't really necessary even in Rails 2.3. There already exists an aptly named method "subclasses" injected into Class by ActiveSupport that returns them for you in lexically sorted order. So you could have written

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.select_options
    subclasses.map{ |c| c.to_s }
  end
end

class Child3 < Parent
end

class Child1 < Parent
end

class Child2 < Parent
end
```

Or you could have used the same trick as they did there and used

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.select_options
    Object.subclasses_of(self).map{ |c| c.to_s }.sort
  end
end
```

Just verified this in Rails 2.3.14 (Ruby 1.8.7-p352) and got the expected result in both cases:

```
>> Parent.select_options
=> ["Child1", "Child2", "Child3"]
```

The necessity to preload STI child classes in the development environment still applies. Kudos to Alex Reisner for the hint in his [blog](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html).

Comment: That link in your last sentence has [moved to here](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails). And it is an excellent read on STI that previous searching hadn't turned up. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you may wish to titleize the classes for presentation to the user. Here is [my version](https://gist.github.com/dissolved/7794471)

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke your `Parent.select_options` method your child models may not be loaded yet. So, you can add something like this:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "*.rb")].each do |f|
    Parent.const_get(File.basename(f, '.rb').classify)
  end
end
```

in your `Parent` model. Now you can use your method:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > Parent.descendants.map {|c| c.to_s}.sort
 => ["Child1", "Child2", "Child3"]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my problem wasn't the load order of the child models, it was the 'descendants' method not existing in Rails 2.3. That is a good idea though, and I'd probably set up an initializer to do that instead of sticking it in the model